# Retrive data of last month using Python with source as MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am getting an error while retrieving data of the last month using python. What is the best approach for the given piece of code?

```
last_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
start_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=last_day_of_prev_month.day)
previous_month_data = "SELECT * from " + tableName + " between UsageDateTime " + str(start_day_of_prev_month) + " AND " + str(last_day_of_prev_month)
print(previous_month_data)
mycursor.execute(previous_month_data)
results = mycursor.fetchall()
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",70)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

I am not able to get solution, What changes can I do. I am using MYSQL as my source database and Python 3.7.4 as my programming language.

Since error is big, posting it in two parts :

**Part1**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRX00.png)

**Part2**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H35mW.png)

Comment: share the output of `print(previous_month_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `WHERE` clause:

```
previous_month_data = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE UsageDateTime BETWEEN '" + str(start_day_of_prev_month) + "' AND '" + str(last_day_of_prev_month) + "'"
```

But I prefer to use `?` placeholders for the parameters and pass them as a tuple:

```
previous_month_data = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE UsageDateTime BETWEEN ? AND ?"
mycursor.execute(previous_month_data, (str(start_day_of_prev_month), str(last_day_of_prev_month)))
```

Note that if the column `UsageDateTime`'s data type is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` then instead of `WHERE UsageDateTime BETWEEN ...` you should use `WHERE DATE(UsageDateTime) BETWEEN ...`, otherwise you will miss the rows of the last day of the month.

Comment: Thanks! Placeholder worked well. Also, I had where clause in my code but due to some mistake where clause is deleted in this question. Nevertheless, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

What's the data type of `UsageDateTime` field.
If it is `datetime`, try this.

```py
previous_month_data = "SELECT * from " + tableName + " between UsageDateTime CAST(" + str(start_day_of_prev_month) + " AS DATE) AND CAST(" + str(last_day_of_prev_month) + " AS DATE"
```

Comment: Data type for UsageDateTime is Date. Will it have an issue at the end of the each month period?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use f-strings for sql queries with variables:

```
previous_month_data = f'''SELECT * from {tableName}  WHERE UsageDateTime  between {start_day_of_prev_month} AND {last_day_of_prev_month}'''
```